# How to use fonts in email templates?

Tags: email, cakephp

How to use fonts like Oswald and Dosis, in email templates which content is sending using php mail function in cakephp?

Answer (score 0):

Oswald and Dosis are both web-fonts as I am sure you know. 
The problem with most e-mail clients is that they do not support web fonts at all, or have bad support for it at best.

You can include the web-fonts (url:s) and corresponding css in the header of your email, but make sure you have a backup font like Arial, Verdana or Sans.

A good rule of thumb regarding the css is to keep as much as you can inline as some of the major email readers like Gmail webmail and MSN webmail ignores the html header all together.